# Access value of a given key in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a list of dictionaries such as:

```
list_ = [
        { 'name' : 'date',
          'value': '2021-01-01'
        },
        { 'name' : 'length',
          'value': '500'
        },
        { 'name' : 'server',
          'value': 'g.com'
        },
```

How can I access the value where the key name == length?

I want to avoid iteration if possible, and just be able to check if the key called 'length'  exists, and if so, get its value.

Comment: It seems like you are confusing `key` with `value`. The strings in front of the `:` are the `keys`.

Comment: Won't be able to do it with this structure, if the values for the "name" keys are unique you could build a dictionary mapping "name" to "value"

Comment: "I want to avoid iteration if possible" it's not, not with this data structure. You can use code that doesn't make the iteration obvious, but it will be checking items one at a time either way.

Comment: How do I do it with iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With iteration, and using [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), you could do:

```
list_ = [
    {'name': 'date',
     'value': '2021-01-01'
     },
    {'name': 'length',
     'value': '500'
     },
    {'name': 'server',
     'value': 'g.com'
     }
]

res = next(dic["value"] for dic in list_ if dic.get("name", "") == "length")
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
500
```

As an alternative, if the `"names"` are unique you could build a dictionary to avoid further iterations on `list_`, as follows:

```
lookup = {d["name"] : d["value"] for d in list_}
res = lookup["length"]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
500
```

Notice that if you need a second key such as `"server"`, you won't need to iterate, just do:

```
lookup["server"]  # g.com
```

Answer (score 1):

It sure is hard to find an element in a list without iterating through it. Thats the first solution I will show:

```
list(filter(lambda element: element['name'] == 'length', list_))[0]['value']
```

this will filter through your list only the elements with name 'length', choose the first from that list, then select the 'value' of that element.

Now, if you had a better data structure, you wouldn't have to iterate. In order to create that better data structure, unfortunately, we will have to iterate the list. A list of dicts with "name" and "value" could really just be a single dict where "name" is the `key` and "value" is the `value`. To create that dict:

```
dict_ = {item['name']:item['value'] for item in list_}
```

then you can just select `'length'`

```
dict_['length']
```

Comment: The thing is that with lists in Python, you can use the 'in' operator. For instance given a list such as [ 1,2,3 ], you can say if 2 in list, instead of iterating over it. I was hoping you can do the same with the list of dictionaries.

Comment: Under the covers, `in` is almost certainly doing an iteration on a list. So unless you mean "without explicitly writing a for loop," I don't think what you are thinking of is possible.